# No internet connection - Android Firebase Flutter RTD

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

When building an .apk of my flutter app and installing on my android device the data created is only locally saved not saved online. When using in the android emulator it works perfectly with no errors, even when switching the signing configs to use debug.

There are no firebase rules set, everyone can read and write. There is no fingerprint/sha1 hash set. All android settings have stayed the same since the build version has worked on android correctly.

If there is anything code etc. i can give please ask, not sure what is helpful here as all settings were the same when it was working.

Answer (score 0):

You have not granted internet permission to access the application

Open the AndroidManifest.xml file located at ./android/app/src/main and add the following line:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="...">
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <!-- Add this -->
</manifest>
```

Refer [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest)

Comment: I already had this, the app was working correctly before without editing any of the settings